# Javascript Caesar Cypher only outputting empty string

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I'm trying to create a Caesar Cypher in JS.  It's supposed to take a string and a number and move every letter in the string over in the alphabet by the provided number, and then return the cypher string.

I wrote some code that changes every letter to it's ASCII code and then adds the input number to it, and converts that back to a string.  However, when I run the code, all I get is an empty string.

My code is below.  (And yes, I know it can be condensed but I'm still fairly new to JS).

```js
const caesar = function(string, num) {

  let solved = "";

  let stringArray = Array.from(string);
  let asciiArray = [];

  for (let i = stringArray[0]; i < stringArray.length; i++) {
    let asciiNum = stringArray.charChodeAt(i);

    if (asciiNum >= 65 && asciiNum <= 90 || asciiNum >= 97 && asciiNum <= 122) {
      asciiArray += asciiNum;
    }
  };

  for (let i = asciiArray[0]; i < asciiArray.length; i++) {
    asciiArray.map(function() {
      asciiArray[i] += num;
    });
  };

  let cypherArray = [];

  for (let i = asciiArray[0]; i < asciiArray.length; i++) {
    cypherArray += asciiArray[i].charCodeAt(0);
  };

  solved = cypherArray.join();


  return solved;
};

console.log(caesar("hello", 2));
```

Comment: do you mean to do a push into the ascii array here: asciiArray += asciiNum;

Comment: Read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for tips on debugging your code. As a beginner programmer, this is one of the most important skills for you to learn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's quite a lot wrong with your code.

1) You have a typo with `charChodeAt`.

2) You're not adding anything to your arrays (you need to `push` elements into arrays).

3) The opposite of [`charCodeAt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt) is [`fromCharCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode) which you need for that final loop.

4) You should look at the documentation for both those methods because the way you were `charCodeAt` was incorrect.

5) You didn't need that `map`.

6) You needed to specify a separator for `join`.

Apart from that it was fine!

```js
const caesar = function(string, num) {

  let solved = "";

  let stringArray = Array.from(string);
  let asciiArray = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i++) {
    let asciiNum = stringArray[i].charCodeAt(0);

    if (asciiNum >= 65 && asciiNum <= 90 || asciiNum >= 97 && asciiNum <= 122) {
      asciiArray.push(asciiNum);
    }
  };

  for (let i = 0; i < asciiArray.length; i++) {
    asciiArray[i] = asciiArray[i] += num;
  };

  let cypherArray = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < asciiArray.length; i++) {
    cypherArray.push(String.fromCharCode(asciiArray[i]));
  };

  solved = cypherArray.join('');

  return solved;

};

console.log(caesar('javascript', 1));
```

Comment: this is not a proper Caesar Cipher; `caesar("javascript", 10)` yields `"tk_k}m|sz~"` (where `_` is an unprintable character). The expected result is `"tkfkcmbszd"`

Comment: I know, but I'm basing this off what the OP had written.

Comment: The code is a creation of a “broken” idea; fix the source, not the side-effect.

Comment: That's not what the question is asking though.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is give us a small challenge: `caesar("a", 1)` gives `"b"`, `caesar("a", 5)` gives `"f"`, but what about `caesar("x", 5)`?

When a letter is shifted beyond `"z"`, [Caesar Cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher) says it should wrap around to the beginning: `ceasar("x", 5)` would go `x -> y -> z -> a -> b -> c`, with a final result of `"c"`. We'll want to make sure our program has this behaviour for lowercase and uppercase letters.

For this kind of problem, rather than writing one big function that does everything, it helps to break it down into smaller pieces -

```js
const toAscii = (char = "") =>
  char.charCodeAt(0)

const fromAscii = (n = 0) =>
  String.fromCharCode(n)

const shiftAscii = (a = 0, shift = 0) =>
  shiftLower(a, shift) || shiftUpper(a, shift) || a

const shiftLower = (a = 0, shift = 0) =>
  a >= 65 && a <= 90
    ? (a - 65 + shift) % 26 + 65
    : 0

const shiftUpper = (a = 0, shift = 0) =>
  a >= 97 && a <= 122
    ? (a - 97 + shift) % 26 + 97
    : 0

const caesarShift = (str = "", num = 0) =>
  Array
    .from(str, char => fromAscii(shiftAscii(toAscii(char), num)))
    .join("")

console.log(caesarShift("Hello, World!", 1))
// Ifmmp, Xpsme!

console.log(caesarShift("Hello, World!", 10))
// Rovvy, Gybvn!
```

We combine small programs to make bigger ones. These larger programs are easy to write and easily communicate what they're doing. This is thanks to the complexity of each concern being isolated in smaller programs -

```
const shiftAscii = (a = 0, shift = 0) =>
  // shift a lowercase ascii, or shift an uppercase ascii, or just return a
  shiftLower(a, shift) || shiftUpper(a, shift) || a

const caesarShift = (str = "", num = 0) =>
  Array
    // for each char, convert to ascii, shift by num, the convert from ascii
    .from(str, char => fromAscii(shiftAscii(toAscii(char), num)))
    // join the array back into a string
    .join("")
```

We see a pattern in `shiftLower` and `shiftUpper`, giving us an opportunity to learn about higher-order functions -

```
const shifter = (min = 0, max = 0) =>
  (a = 0, shift = 0) =>
    a >= min && a <= max
      ? (a - min + shift) % 26 + min
      : 0

const shiftLower =
  shifter(65, 90)

const shiftUpper =
  shifter(97, 122)
```

The output is the same, but we save on duplicating the complex shifting logic -

```js
const toAscii = (char = "") =>
  char.charCodeAt(0)

const fromAscii = (n = 0) =>
  String.fromCharCode(n)

const shiftAscii = (a = 0, shift = 0) =>
  shiftLower(a, shift) || shiftUpper(a, shift) || a

const shifter = (min = 0, max = 0) =>
  (a = 0, shift = 0) =>
    a >= min && a <= max
      ? (a - min + shift) % 26 + min
      : 0
    
const shiftLower =
  shifter(65, 90)

const shiftUpper =
  shifter(97, 122)

const caesarShift = (str = "", num = 0) =>
  Array
    .from(str, char => fromAscii(shiftAscii(toAscii(char), num)))
    .join("")

console.log(caesarShift("Hello, World!", 1))
// Ifmmp, Xpsme!

console.log(caesarShift("Hello, World!", 10))
// Rovvy, Gybvn!
```

JavaScript supports destructuring assignment that allows us to easily work with iterable values, which includes Strings. Using this technique, we can free our mind of things like `Array.from`, Array "mapping", and `Array.prototype.join`. We can write `caesarShift` more like a math formula -

```
const None =
  Symbol ()

const caesarShift = ([ char = None, ...more ], num = 0) =>
  // terminating condition
  char === None
    // base case: no input char; return empty solution
    ? ""
    // inductive: shift the char and append to solution of smaller problem
    : fromAscii(shiftAscii(toAscii(char), num)) + caesarShift(more, num)

console.log(caesarShift("Hello, World!", 1))
// Ifmmp, Xpsme!

console.log(caesarShift("Hello, World!", 10))
// Rovvy, Gybvn!
```

When we write complex programs with countless `let myVar = ..., myOtherVar = ...` and `if (...) { ... } else { ... }` and `for (...) { ... }`, these are all areas for us to make mistakes. In contrast, if we write our programs like formulae, we can combine smaller formulae to write a bigger, more complex formula. We are then less likely to introduce errors – and in the event errors *do* occur, they're easier to find and correct because each formula is only doing a simple thing.